# how can i run sieve on a cyrus-imap folder?

Tags: email, imap, cyrus, sieve

I have a sieve script which I would like to run on a folder in my cyrus imap setup.
The script is already working fine processing newly incoming mail, but I have to run it on the old mail archive, too.

Is there an easy way to do that? or an easy way to "re-deliver" the mails without adding extra headers to them?

Answer (score 1):

Via the admin user you can upload SIEVE scripts into the global namespace.  These can be attached to folders via annotation and will be executed when a message is delivered to the folder.